# REGEX needed in Java for extracting all WARN messages with description may or may not be multiline message

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, multiline, regex-greedy

I am trying to write a regular expression for Input text, where i have to extract all WARN code with the message ahead. In general the WARN may or may not be multiline as shown below.

```
[C] L1250 WARN  k2 bw34 Flex - Sockets:<16>, ThreadsPerCore:<1>
[C] L1250 WARN  For abcd (analytical and transactional workloads). For 12s Systems and above, should be
                disabled.
[C] L1250 INFO  For abcd (analytical workloads), Hyperthreading should be enabled , 8s, 12s, 14d, 34t
                d above.
[C] L1250 WARN  Intel's Hyperthreading on 18+ Socket system disabled. Should be disabled urgently
                fix it!
[C] L1300 OK    CPU governors set as recommended
[C] L1250 WARN  Intel's Hyperthreading on 8+ Socket system disabled.
```

Initially, i started with regex: (WARN).*(\b|\B), this captures till end of word/non word boundary, which does not capture following  multiline(continuing WARN description).

Then i tried-> WARN.+([\S\s]*?)+(?=\[C\]) but this does not capture last WARN line, as there is no further [C] marker.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get your matches without using `[\s\S]*` or the single line option by matching all lines that do not start with `[C]`

```
\bWARN\h+.*(?:\R(?!\[C]).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `\bWARN` Match WARN preceded by a word boundary to prevent being part of a larger word
- `\h+.*` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\R(?!\[C]).*` Match unicode newline sequence, assert that the string does not start with `[C]`
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z0FkB0/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/WAjGia)

For example:

```
String regex = "\\bWARN\\h+.*(?:\\R(?!\\[C]).*)*";
String string = "[C] L1250 WARN  k2 bw34 Flex - Sockets:<16>, ThreadsPerCore:<1>\n"
     + "[C] L1250 WARN  For abcd (analytical and transactional workloads). For 12s Systems and above, should be\n"
     + "                disabled.\n"
     + "[C] L1250 INFO  For abcd (analytical workloads), Hyperthreading should be enabled , 8s, 12s, 14d, 34t\n"
     + "                d above.\n"
     + "[C] L1250 WARN  Intel's Hyperthreading on 18+ Socket system disabled. Should be disabled urgently\n"
     + "                fix it!\n"
     + "[C] L1300 OK    CPU governors set as recommended\n"
     + "[C] L1250 WARN  Intel's Hyperthreading on 8+ Socket system disabled.";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output

```
WARN  k2 bw34 Flex - Sockets:<16>, ThreadsPerCore:<1>
WARN  For abcd (analytical and transactional workloads). For 12s Systems and above, should be
                disabled.
WARN  Intel's Hyperthreading on 18+ Socket system disabled. Should be disabled urgently
                fix it!
WARN  Intel's Hyperthreading on 8+ Socket system disabled.
```

---

If the `[C]` is not a boundary, another option is the check if the next line does not contain one of `WARN`, `INFO` or `OK`

```
 \bWARN\h+.*(?:\R(?!.*\h(?:WARN|INFO|OK)\h).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RjkUv8/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "\\bWARN\\h+.*(?:\\R(?!.*\\h(?:WARN|INFO|OK)\\h).*)*";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex with option **global** and **single line**: `WARN.*?(?=\[C\]|$)`

This will find everything starting with WARN until the next '[C]' or the end of the input string.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/KZXWwL/1

Comment: An extra blank was also getting appended after using the suggested regex with Pattern.DotAll, which i later trimmed. It helped ... thanks :)